# Feature selection based on groups during bagging and boosting step

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, feature-selection

Is there an ml library, with the implementation of ensemble trees (RF or Boosted) which allows randomized feature selection (max_features in sklearn implementation of RFR and GBR or colsample_bytree in xgboost implementation) based on some feature grouping, rather than randomized over complete feature set, for each tree.

e.g. Say I have 10 independent features namely (F1,....F10) but these features can be grouped based on subject knowledge in 4 broad group as

```
{## FG short for feature_group
FG1 : [F1, F2],
FG2: [F3, F4, F5],
FG3: [F6,F7,F8],
FG4: [F9, F10]
}
```

Now with setting of `max_feature = 0.2` in current randomized feature selection methodology, each tree will get any of 10 choose 2 features from 10 features. But I want to constraint feature selection at the group level, such that for one tree if FG1 and FG4 are chosen then all features in those groups are selected [F1,F2,F9,F10].

P.S. I have already created a Random forest Classifier to handle this using **ML-From-Scratch** library and find much robust result compared to randomized feature selection, but using post modeling steps such as MLI (shap or lime) is a challenge.

Comment: Please re-read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that recommendation requests are off-topic.

Comment: Is there some way to do it using xgboost or scikit-learn, without editing code